# How to override Rowkey sorting in hbase table HFiles?

Tags: sorting, hbase, row-key

I wonder whether there is a way to override the Rowkey sorting strategies while creating a new hbase table? can I for example sort in inverse order?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Rows are meant to be stored lexicographically. What you CAN do, however, is to scan the rows in reverse order. Or you could create some sort of "MAX-" heuristics according to which your rows would be decreasing from some max value, or turning negative. In this case you have to be careful with hotspotting.

Comment: Yes, thank you I already proceeded as you mentioned, I concatenated that sort of MAX-amount to the date in the row Key so the data is listed in desc sorting :)